# php webservices to twitter

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

can i tweet from webservice to twitter using oAuth?
Could anyone please tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

The following PHP Twitter libraries support OAuth:

- [twitteroauth](http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)
- [twitter-async](http://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async)
- [Twitter API CodeIgniter Library](http://www.haughin.com/code/twitter/)

They are fairly similar: about the only difference is that twitter-async uses asynchronous Curl calls to Twitter which may be faster depending on what you are doing with the Twitter API.

Comment: what im face is,how to click automatically ALLOW button when a page An application would like to connect to your account is appear?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't. The OAuth workflow should be that they allow you once. After that, you store the returned key and use that.

Comment: becouse its a API webservice,user cant click ALLOW buttton.suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a one to one mapping between a twitter account, and your web service, you still need to authorize an access token at least once.

Once you have an authorized access token, you can make twitter requests as needed.

Just a guess that this is what you want though...